# How to Poll a request for certain interval and determine Pass or Failure

Tags: cucumber, karate

I've the API request as below :

```
* def reqCreate =  read('classpath:integration/create-request.json')

* def resCreate = read('classpath:integration/create-response.json')

* def personId = 12



 Given path '/person/' + personId
        And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        When method get
        Then status 200
        Then match response == resCreate
```

I need to check the response after every 5 seconds till one minute.During one minute or till one minutes any any moment, if response assertion gives true then final result is true else should return false after specified duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained clearly in the documentation : https://github.com/intuit/karate#retry-until

```
* configure retry = { count: 12, interval: 5000 }
Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'greeting'
And retry until response.id > 3
When method get
Then status 200
```

In your case :

```
Given path '/person/' + personId
And configure retry = { count: 12, interval: 5000 }
And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
And retry until response == resCreate
When method get
Then status 200
```

Please don't forget to mark your previous questions as answered, you have a few that you left open.